# Two trunks from two switches to router

Tags: redundancy

I want to connect two switches with 6 vlans to a router. Both switches are connected to other switches and are there for redundancy. Router doesn't let me put same default gateways on both  interfaces (or better say, all subinterfaces of both interfaces). How to proceed?

EDIT:

Cisco 2811. Please, could you write the procedure for SVI?

EDIT2:

I have connected it through SVI but how can I get inter-vlan routing? on sw ports on the router I can't create subinterfaces.

Answer (score 2):

What router make and model?
You can't have the same IP on two routed interfaces. It looks like you simply need an SVI (VLAN interface) on the router and the two downlink ports on that VLAN, assuming your router supports VLANS.

To use VLANs on a Cisco 2811 you need to use an ESW module, there are cheap four port models you can buy (ESW-4FE). 
But as you can actually set an IP address on your interfaces I'd take it you have normal routed interfaces.

On routed interfaces you can as an alternative use a bridge interface (BVI) on two routed ports, this less optimal than using VLANs:

For bridge groups:

```
bridge 1 protocol ieee
bridge 1 route ip
!
int bvi1
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
 no shut
!
int f0/0
  bridge-group 1
!
int f0/1
  bridge-group 1
!
```

Remember to make sure the two switches don't start communicating with each other over this interface though! All traffic on routed interfaces hits the router CPU.